# Что-нибудь вроде onload для videoView

Tags: android, videoview

Моё videoview видео подгружается через интернет (player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("example.com/1.mp4"));)

Как узнать, когда оно загрузилось и готово к просмотру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что Вам необходимо установить callback

```
public void setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)
```

В документации написано, что указанный callback вызовется, когда данные будут загружены.
Ссылка - [public void setOnPreparedListener (MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)](http://bit.ly/XbuCjF)

Answer (score 0):

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
 //код выполниться после загрузки видео
}